# Efficient subtype testing

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, typing

Languages like Java, C#, Eiffel, and C++ have subtype hierarchies which are directed acyclic graphs, due to interfaces in Java and C# and multiple inheritance in Eiffel and C++. An obvious way to check whether type $A$ is a subtype of type $B$ is to traverse the graph of the subtype hierarchy starting at $A$ to see whether type $B$ appears 'above' it. This surely is not the most efficient way to implement subtype tests.

> What techniques exist to efficiently implement subtype testing for modern OO languages?

I'm interested in efficiency both in terms of time and memory and any trade-offs between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Yves Caseau gave a method for efficiently encoding type hierarchies as bit vectors. See [Efficient handling of multiple inheritance hierarchies](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=165905).

Comment: Can you provide some more details, to make your answer more self-contained?